# the cv::imshow() miss some images , only show the last image

Tags: c++, opencv, graphics

The original idea was that, when you hold down A, the object will be rotated 10 degrees around the z-axis every 10ms, and then displayed on the screen.

Because of some problems, I reinstalled the system. There may be some changes in the environment that I don't know about. Now I press and hold A, the image will not rotate, but the degree in the program is changing. When I release A, It will draw the final state of the object on the screen

The only thing that is same is that the effect of tapping the A key.

what should I do?

```cpp
while (key != 27)
{
    r.clear(rst::Buffers::Color | rst::Buffers::Depth);

    // r.set_model(get_model_matrix(angle));
    r.set_model(get_rotation(axis_default, angle)); // set rotation axis to Z, angle default 0
    r.set_view(get_view_matrix(eye_pos));
    r.set_projection(get_projection_matrix(45, 1, 0.1, 50));

    r.draw(pos_id, ind_id, rst::Primitive::Triangle);

    cv::Mat image(700, 700, CV_32FC3, r.frame_buffer().data());
    image.convertTo(image, CV_8UC3, 1.0f);
    cv::imshow("image", image);
    key = cv::waitKey(10);

    std::cout << "frame count: " << frame_count++ << '\n';

    if (key == 'a')
    {
        angle += 10;
    }
    else if (key == 'd')
    {
        angle -= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding after the `if` - `else`: a loop like: `if (key == 'a' || key == 'd') {for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {cv::waitKey(1);} }`. If it's not working, edit your question - post something we can build and execute.

Comment: it works! Thanks. Why  it can run normally after adding this loop, and why  it can run normally without this in the previous system

Comment: I no nothing about the "previous system"... When the user holds a key, `cv::waitKey(10)` returns immediately - without waiting 10msec, and probably without refreshing the displayed image. Using a loop that waits 1msec 10 times solves the issue (I am not exactly sure why).